# mssql+php prepared statements incorrect syntax using %

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, syntax

I have this little code snippet:

```
$sql .= " (cOriginalFilename LIKE %?%)";
```

and this is the full query:

```
Select  cMsgID, 
        cDocType, 
        cOriginalFilename, 
        cSubAddress1, 
        cRecipientID, 
        cSenderID, 
        cStatus, 
        cStatusDateTime
From    tMessages
Where   (cOriginalFilename LIKE %?%)
```

Exact error message:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. ) )

As you can see it is making a prepared statement but it is giving me an invalid syntax error. When I remove the %s it works. How should I modify the syntax to work with the %s? I couldn't find any info on this topic.

note: This is php and mssql

Comment: @Siyual Thank you, that worked! I'm never good at making figuring out syntaxes. If you post you comment as an answer I would gladly select it as the solving answer.

Comment: One step ahead of ya, lol.  And no prob :)

Comment: stackoverflow refreshes weridly for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close - the `%` wildcards just need to be quoted for this:

```
Select  cMsgID, 
        cDocType, 
        cOriginalFilename, 
        cSubAddress1, 
        cRecipientID, 
        cSenderID, 
        cStatus, 
        cStatusDateTime
From    tMessages
Where   (cOriginalFilename LIKE '%' + ? + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

The % signs need to go in the variable that you assign to the parameter, instead of in the query.

Comment: I think this explanation is just as good. I typically put the `%` in the values.

Comment: Ty @Evert , was wondering why I got downvoted. But I'm not the only one using this.